# Confused by lambda output in this case

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

After learning lambda in C++11, I wrote this and got confused by the output.

```
auto f1 = [] () {
    int tmp = 10;
    int *tmp_p = &tmp;
    return [tmp_p] (int x) {
        return *tmp_p + x;
    };
}();

auto f2 = []() {
    int tmp = 10;
    return [&tmp] (int x) {
        return tmp + x;
    };
}();

cout << f1(5) << endl;
cout << f1(5) << endl;

cout << f2(5) << endl;
cout << f2(5) << endl;
```

Output is:

```
15
5772973
2686617
2686617
```

What's the reason behind this?

Comment: But they return lambdas with parameters and are executed immediately

Comment: @AdrianJałoszewski sorry just noticed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because undefined behavior.

`tmp` gets destructed after `f1` is assigned, and so `tmp_p` becomes a dangling pointer. Anything can happen when you dereference it, including sometimes given the right value `15`, and sometimes not `5772973`.

The same goes for `f2`, but instead of using a pointer, you use a reference, which references a destructed object, which is also undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5):

This is what we call [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Why is your code causing undefined behavior?

First case: `f1()`:
It's causing it, because after calling these lambdas the values of `int tmp` and `int *tmp_p` aren't on the stack anymore (the `int *tmp_p` was copied but the `int tmp` was removed).

Second case: `f2()`: The value of `tmp` was accessed by reference to the inner lambda. After the generating lambda finished it wasn't on the stack anymore and something obtained the memory and wrote garbage into it.